# How to get an object(handle) of a javascript file?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am using requireJS and I have two files (app,js and file1.js). I need to instantiate file1.js in app.js using require() and then call a function in file1.js from app.js. How do I do that?

> app.js

```
define(function(require){
    var file1 = require('file1.js');
    file1.load_function();
}
```

> file1.js

```
define([], function(){
    var load_function = function(){
        //Some logic
    }
}
```

But here, the "load_function()" is being loaded without being invoked. And there is error in the way I am using "var file1" as a handle.

Is there a way I can get a handle on "file1.js" from "app.js"?

How can  prevent the function from loading(executing) without it being invoked?

Comment: i think you are close, you need to check your syntax and fiddle with it. you should be naming file1 as a dependency of app, and using file1's guts in a callback on the app require. in short, find an existing working example of a basic nested require call and modify the file and function names to fit your code.

Answer (score 0):

There is no error in your `app.js` file. The line `var file1 = require('file1.js');` loads the module `file1.js` and binds it to the local variable `file1`. Then you can call `file1.load_function()`.

You need to export your function:

```
define(function (require, exports, module) {
    var load_function = function(){
        //Some logic
    }
    exports.load_function = load_function;
});
```

By the way you should never put the `.js` extension in your module names so refer to the module in the file named `file1.js` as `file1`.

Comment: Will using exports give me a handle from app.js?. "file1" is the name I gave for this question, the actual module has an appropriate name :)

Comment: Ok, then I've removed that comment.

Comment: Everything else in what you are doing looks fine to me. You *are* in fact loading `file1` with `var file1 = require('file1.js');` It is just not working when you call `load_function` because you do not export it.

Comment: I get an error when I remove the '.js'. Not a primary concern right now :)

Comment: You probably have an error somewhere else, that the `.js` cancels. This is a case of two errors cancelling each other. Adding the `.js` at the end of a module name changes how RequireJS resolves the name.

Comment: Is it a valid way of calling the function? "file1.function_name"? Does "file1" act as a handle to the actual JS file here?

Comment: `file1.function_name()` is a valid way to call the function. The variable `file1` refers to the module.